# Long table description in kable and stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer, kable, kableextra

That is how I produce tables in stargazer now:

```
set.seed(1)
data1 <- data.table(x = seq(200), y = 2*seq(200) + rnorm(200, sd = 10))

model <- lm(y ~ x, data1)
summary(model)

stargazer(model, 
      title = "Regression results", align = TRUE, header = FALSE,
      no.space = FALSE,
      font.size = "small",
      df = FALSE)
```

How do I modify the code to add a long table description before the table starts? I actually have the same question regarding kable - I can specify the caption by

```
my_table %>% kable("latex", booktabs = T, caption = "Summary statistics")
```

How do I insert a long description of the table which is located above it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Latex code you want just before the table starts:

```
set.seed(1)
data1 <- data.table(x = seq(200))
data1[, y:= 2*x + rnorm(200, sd = 10)]

model <- lm(y ~ x, data1)
summary(model)

star <-stargazer(model, 
          title = "Regression results", align = TRUE, header = FALSE,
          no.space = FALSE,
          font.size = "small",
          df = FALSE)

star_2 <- c(star[1:2], "How do I modify the code to add a long table description before the table starts? Just modify the latex output", star[3:length(star)])
```

I modified your example because I was having an error when creating the `data.table`

Best!

Comment: Thank you! The text was not placed exactly where I need it, but I got your point. So there is no way I can do it by means of stargazer or kable and the only option is to modify the output latex code.